# xarray create variables attributes

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I want to create a dataset with xarray and want to add attributes to variables while creating the dataset. The [xarray documentation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.html) provides a way of adding global attribute.
For example, as below:

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
data_vars=dict(
    'temperature'=(["x", "y", "time"], temperature),
    'precipitation'=(["x", "y", "time"], precipitation),
),
coords=dict(
    lon=(["x", "y"], lon),
    lat=(["x", "y"], lat),
    time=time,
    reference_time=reference_time,
),
attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."),)
```

One way to add variable attribute would be some like this:

```
ds['temperature'].attrs = {"units": K, '_FillValue': -999}
```

But, in my opinion it is more like updating the attribute. Is there a way to directly assign attributes while creating the dataset directly using `xr.Dataset` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can directly define variable attributes when defining the `data_vars`. You just need to provide the attributes in a dictionary Form.
See also: https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/internals/variable-objects.html

In your example above that would be:

```
ds = xr.Dataset(
data_vars=dict(
    temperature=(["x", "y", "time"], temperature,{'units':'K'}),
    precipitation=(["x", "y", "time"], precipitation,{'units':'mm/day'}),
),
coords=dict(
    lon=(["x", "y"], lon),
    lat=(["x", "y"], lat),
    time=time,
    reference_time=reference_time,
),
attrs=dict(description="Weather related data."),)
```

Comment: How about to add attributes for e.g. lat, lon, time (dimmensions), while initializing xr.Dataset?

Comment: Same as for the data_vars, add an attribute dictionary when providing the coords as a tuple, eg.     lon=(["x", "y"], lon,{'units':'Degrees'}),